# How does the coloring work the latest Flutter SVG package (flutter_svg 2.0.0+1)

Tags: flutter, svg

After upgrading the flutter_svg package to the latest version as of this date (2.0.0+1).
The linting says that the color member is depreciated, but there's this parameter called "colorFilter", but it has different enum properties that somehow render differently. Can someone explain how to just add normal color properties to an SVG or how the colorFilter properly works thanks.

[Link to the package on pub dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

[image: Here is an image of the new properties of the colorFilter.mode]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my case, I used `ColorFilter.mode` with `BlendMode.scrIn` and it works fine, other modes didn't seem to be working visually properly. So if you want to set color to svg, it should work if you used it with right `BlendMode`.

P.S
I had bottom navigation where I had to change colors of active svg icons.

[image: code example]

Comment: In case you just get a colored square - you need some parts of the image to be transparent, so make sure it doesn't have a white background or something similar

Answer (score -7):

Please to you SVG package down grade to version and resolve this problem

Comment: the parameter is deprecated for a reason. colorFilter gives wider possibilities then color, so refusing to understand how it works is not that valuable advice. if you are motivated by removing warnings without thinking what they mean, you should reconsider your approach to programming.

Comment: It's better to fix the problem than hide the error